# replace array with new array in object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with two arrays that contain alternative emails and numbers. I'm trying to delete items out of the array and set the new array in the old ones' place.

```
const handleDelteMail = (evt) => {
    let tempData: any = [];
    tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData.emailAlt));
    let filtered = tempData.filter((mail) => mail._id !== evt.currentTarget.value);

    console.log(filtered);

    setUserData({ ...userData, [userData.emailAlt]: filtered });
};
```

filtered holds the correct new array that I want to put into userData, but having no luck.

this is what my userData object looks like:

```
const initialValues = {
    dateCreated: Date.now(),
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    countryCode: "",
    numberPrime: "",
    numberAlt: [],
    companyName: "",
    consultant: "",
    industry: "",
    whatsapp: false,
    acceptTerms: false,
    emailPrime: "",
    emailAlt: [],
    skype: "",
    userType: "",
    agent: "",
    comment: "",
};
```

I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Try this `setUserData({ ...userData, emailAlt: filtered });`. If i remember correctly will [userData.emailAlt] use the value from userData.emailAlt as key.

Answer (score 1):

1. `filter` already returns a new array so you don't need to make a copy of `userData.emailAlt` - just iterate over it.
2. Watch your spelling (`handleDelteMail` should probably be `handleDeleteMail`).
3. You can reconstruct the new object by assigning the new array to `emailAlt`.

```js
function handleDeleteMail(evt) {
  
  const { value } = evt.target;
  
  const filtered = userData.emailAt.filter(mail => {
    return mail._id !== value);
  });

  setUserData({ ...userData, emailAlt: filtered });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function get in module `lodash`

Try this one:

```
const _ = require('lodash'); // install `lodash` first

const { value } = evt.currentTarget;
  
const filtered = userData.emailAt.filter(mail => {
  return mail._id !== value);
});

_.set(userData, 'emailAtl', filtered)
```